# Asking brand-specific / regional questions "responsibly"

Tags: discussion

There's been a lull in new questions lately, so I'd like to lead the way in generating some brand-specific or regional questions [as discussed here](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/73), in hopes of giving confidence and encouraging others to ask such questions (however "taboo"-feeling) comfortably.

One thing I feared about doing this, though, was that **we might ask too many "superficial" questions—questions asked for the sake of asking, not actually solving a specific problem** the asker is having. I felt that such questions, asked with no "skin in the game," would necessarily be of low(er) quality, because we don't tend to think things through as much when we're not *personally* involved.

For example, I'm currently in San Diego but originally from New York City and visit family and friends there often, so when asking about NYC, I have some vested interest in getting *useful* answers, and care more about specificity, *e.g.* I don't necessarily want to know about breweries inaccessible by NYC's public transportation system, since I almost never have a car while there. Such considerations would not enter my mind were I asking about, for example, Austin, TX, a place I've never been and don't have any current plans to visit.

So, I propose that, **while we *should* feel comfortable asking questions about brands and regions, we should ask "responsibly," *i.e.* ask questions we earnestly imagine ourselves *making use of* in an upcoming trip or encounter—questions that benefit us *personally*.**

Feel free to link this meta post when asking regional questions, as a "disclaimer." That's why I'm writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that people ask these questions **when you have a real question**.  Asking questions just to populate a site is no good; they tend to be shallow and superficial, and if even the *asker* doesn't really care, why should *answerers* be motivated to invest effort?  On the other hand, if you have an actual question that you care about, please do ask it, giving us more than a one-liner.  (What motivates the question? What have you already investigated?  Etc.)

Limiting it to questions people actually care about should mitigate the fear of flooding the site with trivial questions.  On the other hand, barring *all* of them just because *some* could be abusive, with our current question rate, seems unwise.

Answer (score 1):

Generally all stackexchange answers should be answerable within a certain scope. You will have  a ton of same styled questions and answers where one region is just swapped out for another.

This would mean that technically you couldn't stop anyone from going on an asking spree as it would not be out of scope. So my personal opinion on this subject is to not allow it. Defining "responsibly" will be too open ended.

I believe your questions would be appropriate for the chat, but not for the main site.